# Adding *n of nights in the date given using php

Tags: php, date

So what i am trying to do is for the function to return a string like this
January 19-20, 2018
the variables all i have are the initial date and the number of nights. Too bad there's no way to getDate or getYear like js. Thanks for the help

Comment: There’s no way to get the year or day from a date in PHP? None? Whatsoever?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom function:

```
function showDates($startDate, $nights) {
    $d1=new DateTime($startDate);
    $d2 = new DateTime($startDate);
    $d2->add(new DateInterval("P10D")); 
    if ($d2->format('Y') == $d1->format('Y')) {
        $year = $d1->format('Y');
    } else {
        $year = $d1->format('Y') . '-' . $d2->format('Y');
    }
    if ($d2->format('m') == $d1->format('m')) {
        $month = $d1->format('F');
    } else {
        $month = $d1->format('F') . '-' . $d2->format('F');
    }
    if ($d2->format('d') == $d1->format('d')) {
        $day = $d1->format('d');
    } else {
        $day = $d1->format('d') . '-' . $d2->format('d');
    }

    return $month . ' ' . $day . ' ' . $year;
}

echo showDates("2017-10-05 12:00:00", 3);
```